# Update table column value with SSIS package Name

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am creating .cvs file by SSIS. 
Once .cvs file is created then I need to update one of the **table column value**  with created **SSIS package Name** just to indicate that rows are exported to .cvs file.

msdn.dbo.sysssispackege this does not work for me , I need other options to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution here: Please go to the link
    http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s359/files-foreach.htm